# convert amount into words in NPR format in odoo12?

Tags: odoo-12

I want to convert amount in words in NPR format but it always shows in Euro and cents only. How to change it to NPR format while converting into words.

I have tried all the method lang also but euro and cent cannot be replaced. My company currency is NPR but not able to convert it. I have `currency_id` field relating to `res.currency`.

I have tried code as below:

```
@api.depends('amount')
    def set_amt_in_words(self):
        self.amt_inwords = num2words(self.amount, to = 'currency',  lang = 'en_IN')
        if self.currency_id == 'NPR':
            amt_inwords = str(amt_inwords).replace('Euro', 'rupees')
            amt_inwords = str(amt_inwords).replace('Cents', 'paise')
            amt_inwords = str(amt_inwords).replace('Cent', 'paise')
        self.amt_inwords += '\tonly'
        self.amt_inwords = self.amt_inwords.title()
```

I want to output in Rupees and paise.

Comment: Is your main company's currency NPR?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.env.ref('base.NPR').with_context({'lang': 'en_IN'}).amount_to_text(self.amount)
```

The following method belongs to the model `res.currency` and is the responsible for translating currency amount to text (`<path_to_v12>/odoo/addons/base/models/res_currency.py`):

```
@api.multi
def amount_to_text(self, amount):
    self.ensure_one()
    def _num2words(number, lang):
        try:
            return num2words(number, lang=lang).title()
        except NotImplementedError:
            return num2words(number, lang='en').title()

    if num2words is None:
        logging.getLogger(__name__).warning("The library 'num2words' is missing, cannot render textual amounts.")
        return ""

    formatted = "%.{0}f".format(self.decimal_places) % amount
    parts = formatted.partition('.')
    integer_value = int(parts[0])
    fractional_value = int(parts[2] or 0)

    lang_code = self.env.context.get('lang') or self.env.user.lang
    lang = self.env['res.lang'].search([('code', '=', lang_code)])
    amount_words = tools.ustr('{amt_value} {amt_word}').format(
                    amt_value=_num2words(integer_value, lang=lang.iso_code),
                    amt_word=self.currency_unit_label,
                    )
    if not self.is_zero(amount - integer_value):
        amount_words += ' ' + _('and') + tools.ustr(' {amt_value} {amt_word}').format(
                    amt_value=_num2words(fractional_value, lang=lang.iso_code),
                    amt_word=self.currency_subunit_label,
                    )
    return amount_words
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but with_context({'lang':'en_IN'}) shows error : 'bool' object is not subscriptable. so i removed the with_context part and it is running but the format is international. I want it in Lakhs if u have idea then please help me.

Comment: Your database lacks a record on the table `res_lang` having `code='en_IN'`. You can either create the corresponding record or use `en_US` instead. Here is what I got `self.env.ref('base.NPR').with_context({'lang': 'en_US'}).amount_to_text(12.34)`:
'Twelve Rupee and Thirty-Four Paisa'

Comment: Thanks but its working in the same way as u answered. Could u please help me to get the value in Crores and  lakhs not in Billion and Million. If u have any idea please help me. Thanks...

Comment: Edit your question and give me an example of the function call and the expected result